# SQL server: Can NT accounts be mapped to SQL server accounts

Tags: sql-server

In our database we have an SQL server account that has the correct roles to access some of the databases. We are now switching to windows authentication and I was wondering if we can create a NT user group and map the privileges of the SQL server account to the NT user group? So if anyone in the NT user group is authenticated they will have the same privileges as the existing SQL server account.

Or would it be better to just delete the SQL server account and just assign roles to the NT group in SQL server?

JD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you originally had the correct roles associated with those SQL server account, I would use the **roles** to map with the NT User Groups.

When you add those NT Users into SQL Server, you should be able to assign those roles to those accounts.

Comment: Something I am not clear about, does that mean I can remove the SQL server account as I have now mapped the roles to the NT User group?

Comment: Yes. To test it out try to connect to SQL Server using Windows Authentication.  If you can connect and see the right databases then you have set it up correctly.